# Unknown imageview in uiscrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I simply added new uiscrollview from interface builder and in viewDidLoad method I am getting its subview and printing it on console. It shows two image views. I can't figure it out where did they come from.

```
NSArray * views = [friendScrollView subviews];
NSLog(@"views are %@", [views description]);
```

In console:

```
views are (
    "<UIImageView: 0x1b82f0; frame = (805 203; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1b6cb0>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x17b1d0; frame = (805 203; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1bdbd0>>"
)
```

When I remove them they don't even remove from scroll view.
any idea?

Comment: They are not supposed to be removed?Why you need to remove that?

Comment: I need to get lastview's content offset and I am getting different values because of that image views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the vertical and horizontal scroll indicators and they are **not supposed to be removed**

```
UIKIT_CLASS_AVAILABLE(2_0) @interface UIScrollView : UIView <NSCoding> {
    ...
    UIImageView* _verticalScrollIndicator;
    UIImageView* _horizontalScrollIndicator;
```

Answer (score 3):

These image views are the horizontal and vertical scroll indicator images. They are present by default when you create the `UIScrollView` instance.

The iOS HIG guidelines for [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41) specify

> When a scroll view first appears—or when users interact with it—vertical or horizontal scroll indicators flash briefly to show users that there is more content they can reveal.

This is a best practice recommended to be followed to ensure a good user experience. Hence they should not be removed. If at all it is required that the scroll indicators are not to be shown then the scroll view provides [properties to achieve this programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). Set the required property to `NO`

- showsHorizontalScrollIndicator
- showsVerticalScrollIndicator

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
for (UIView *v in friendScrollView.subviews) 
{   
   [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Also use `isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]` to only remove imageviews from scrollview in case you have subview of friendScrollView other than imageviews.

Comment: They are not supposed to be removed